# Sequelize version 3.30.2 - execute raw query in migration

Tags: node.js, migration, sequelize.js

So I have to perform a complex migration, and for my version of sequelize I have to use plain old SQL. This happens because in version 3.30 `QueryInterface` does not include the `addConstraint` and `removeConstraint`.

How can I execute a raw SQL query in my migration file?

**Migration**:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {

    // queryInterface.query does not exist :S
    // queryInterface.raw does not exist :S
    return queryInterface.query(' \
        ALTER TABLE "people" \
        DROP CONSTRAINT "peoplePartners_peopleId_fkey" \
    ');

  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {

  }
};
```

Of course, my real query is way more complex than the one shown above, which is for explanation purposes.

How do I perform a raw query in a db migration file in Sequelize 3.30?

Comment: I'm looking for the same functionality. Were you able to find a solution?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4):

**Background**

The `queryInterface` object has `sequelize` as a property.

The `sequelize` property contains the `query` method.

**Example**

Run a raw SQL query in a migration:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {

    return queryInterface.sequelize.query(`
      ALTER TABLE "people"
      DROP CONSTRAINT "peoplePartners_peopleId_fkey"
    `);
  }
}
```

**Credit to**

[Unable to execute the raw query in Sequelize migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49251948/unable-to-execute-the-raw-query-in-sequelize-migrations)